# How do you check the database for data before patching/putting using angular's observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, http

This is a pretty simple issue I have, I just don't know how to do it as seamless as possible with observables. I would like to check my database for a property value. If it exists, I will patch it with new data. If it doesn't I will put the new data in (adding in the property value to the database). I am running Angular 10.0.7, and using the httpClient as well.

Below what I would like to do:

```
saveData(data: DataObject) {

  this.httpClient.get<DataObject>(
     this.DATA_BASE_URL + this.user.username + ".json"
  ).subscribe(response => {
     response.propertyName = data;
     if (response.hasOwnProperty("propertyName")) {
      this.httpClient.patch(
          this.TEST_DB_URL + this.user.username + ".json",
          response
        ).subscribe(r => {
          console.log(r);
        })
     } else {
      this.httpClient.put(
          this.TEST_DB_URL + this.user.username + ".json",
          response
        ).subscribe(r => {
          console.log(r);
        })
     }
  })

}
```

I'm not sure if it is correct to add the http calls inside the subscribe()  callback. Is there a more conventional or effective way to implement this pattern? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use switchMap, switchmap change one response from a call to another response from the inner call

```
 this.httpClient.get<DataObject>(
     this.DATA_BASE_URL + this.user.username + ".json"
  ).pipe(switchMap(response => {
     //with the response
     response.propertyName = data;
     if (response.hasOwnProperty("propertyName")) {
       return this.httpClient.patch(
          this.TEST_DB_URL + this.user.username + ".json",response
        ))
     } else {
      return this.httpClient.put(
          this.TEST_DB_URL + this.user.username + ".json",response
        )
     }
    })).subscribe(r => {
          console.log(r);
    })
```